# How can I deploy a Maven snapshot to oss.jfrog.org? Return code: 405

Tags: java, maven, artifactory, bintray

There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415722/deploy-snapshot-to-oss-jfrog-org-jcenter) related to this, but the error code is different (409).

In the pom.xml file I added:

```xml
<distributionManagement>
    <!-- Release repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>bintray</id>
        <url>https://api.bintray.com/maven/USERNAME/maven/PACKAGE_NAME;publish=1</url>
    </repository>
    <!-- Snapshot repository -->
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>jfrog-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

And the settings.xml file contains:

```xml
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>bintray</id>
        <username>USERNAME</username>
        <password>API_KEY</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>jfrog-snapshots</id>
        <username>USERNAME</username>
        <password>API_KEY</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

The release is ([almost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31454299/maven-artifact-is-not-yet-publish-in-bintray)) published to BinTray, but when I try to deploy a snapshot it fails with the following error:

> Could not transfer artifact
>   GROUP_ID:ARTIFACT_ID:jar:0.4-20150716.145236-1 from/to jfrog-snapshots
>   (http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-snapshot): Failed to transfer
>   file:
>   http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-snapshot/GROUP_ID/ARTIFACT_ID/0.4-SNAPSHOT/ARTIFACT_ID-0.4-20150716.145236-1.jar.
>   Return code is: **405**, ReasonPhrase: Method Not Allowed. -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`libs-snapshot` is a [virtual repository](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories) which you cannot deploy artifacts to.
You should use the `oss-snapshot-local` repository instead:

```xml
<snapshotRepository>
    <id>jfrog-snapshots</id>
    <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local</url>
</snapshotRepository>
```

For more information see [Deploying Maven and Gradle snapshots to OJO (oss.jfrog.org)](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Deploying+Snapshots+to+oss.jfrog.org)

Comment: As of writing, the link appears to be dead.